# Pooling data after a nested anova

Tags: anova, nested-models

I have a general question (data can be provided if needed). If I ran a nested anova and there is no significant effect of the nested factor on the model, is it reasonable to remove that variable and just run a one way anova?

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with testing a variable for significance and removing it if it leads to a p-value above a threshold (such as $0.05$) and doing the rest of the analysis without that variable is that the downstream analysis, unless you are quite careful (most people will not be), proceeds as if you had not done the pre-test. This means that all of your downstream inferences, such as p-values, confidence intervals, and variance estimates, are at least a bit dubious.

There are ways to be careful with such an approach in order to obtain valid results, but this is a form of stepwise regression, and the issues I have mentioned here are related to issues 1, 2, 3, 4, and 7 [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/). (While the link is for a Stata website, the content is 100% about statistics and is independent of the software used to run your model.)